# Correct way to insert values in Redis with format "Key X , Value A,B,C"

Tags: redis, redis-cli, redisclient

I Have a .csv file with columns like these

| ID | Valuue1 | Value2 | Value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | C |

I'm trying to insert those values in redis where ID will be the KEY and the value will be a string like this

```
"{\"Value1\":\"A\",\"Value2\":\"B\",\"Value3\":\"C\"}"
```

The idea is that from my API I can fetch an ID and use the value as string format or Json ,I tried different ways including the following but I'm not able to get the desired result

```
tail -n +2 dnis.csv | awk -F',' '{print "SET \""$1"\" \""Value $1 Value2 "$2" Value3 "$3""\""}'| redis-cli  pipeline
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: RedisJSON maybe? https://redis.com/blog/redis-as-a-json-store/

Comment: unfortunately that option doesn't work for me because I have to connect to a remote redis instance, I'm not able to add modules and RedisJson is not installed.